# Find longest consecutive time interval per object

Tags: mysql, sql

There are `Merchant`s and they can submit `Claim`s.

I need to find the longest time period during which a `Merchant` had at least 1  claim. So a time period (in fractions of a day, whatever) per `merchant_id`.

So, for example:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| merchant_id |  claim_id |         from         |          to          |
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|           1 |        11 |  2016-08-15 12:00:00 |  2016-08-17 12:00:00 |
|           1 |        22 |  2016-08-16 12:00:00 |  2016-08-18 12:00:00 |
|           1 |        33 |  2016-08-19 12:00:00 |  2016-08-20 12:00:00 |
|           2 |        66 |  2016-08-15 12:00:00 |  2016-08-17 12:00:00 |
|           2 |        67 |  2016-08-18 12:00:00 |  2016-08-19 12:00:00 |
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

For `merchant_id` = 1  it would be 3 days.

For `merchant_id` = 2 it would be 2 days.

How do I do that?

Comment: how would you define someone having *at least 1 open claim*?

Comment: If a merchant has claim - then we can see a claim_id in the table - and it has an open time - open and close time - to

Comment: This is very complicated to do in MySQL, because it doesn't support either CTEs or window functions.

Comment: I'm not certain that I understand the arithmetic - but I *can* see why this might be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this alone in MySQL is really complex. I've tried for a particular `merchant_id`. I am not still sure if this is `100%` right without checking for different set of inputs.

But you can give this a try and later I can explain the logic behind.

```
SELECT 
firstTable.merchant_id,
MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,firstTable.from,secondTable.to)) AS maxConsecutiveDays
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    A.merchant_id,
    A.from,
    @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS row_number
    FROM merchants A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) var
    WHERE A.merchant_id = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM merchants B WHERE B.merchant_id = A.merchant_id AND A.idt <> B.idt AND A.`from` BETWEEN B.from AND  B.to 
    )
    ORDER BY A.from
) AS firstTable

INNER JOIN (

    SELECT 
    A.merchant_id,
    A.to,
    @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS row_number
    FROM merchants A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0) var
    WHERE A.merchant_id = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM merchants B WHERE B.merchant_id = A.merchant_id AND A.idt <> B.idt AND A.to BETWEEN B.from AND  B.to 
    )
    ORDER BY A.to
) AS secondTable 
ON firstTable.row_number = secondTable.row_number;
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c29d2b/1/0)

**Algorithm:**

<sub>Let's consider the following steps for a particular `merchant_id`</sub>

1. **First** find all the start points which are not inside in any of the
   ranges. I call this independent start points. Let's say these start
   points are stored in a set `S`.
2. **Second** now find all the end points which are not inside in any of
   the ranges. These are independent end points and are stored in a set
   `E`.
3. Sort the sets in ascending order of time.
4. Now give a rank to every element of a set starting from 1.
5. Join these two sets on matching rank number.
6. Now enumerate the two sets simultaneously and get the difference in
   days. And later find the maximum of this difference.

<sub>The last step can be illustrated by the following code snippet:</sub>

---

```
int maxDiff = 0;

for(int i=0; i< E.size(); i++){
  if((E.get(i) - S.get(i) > maxDiff){
     maxDiff = E.get(i) - S.get(i);
  }
}
```

And `maxDiff` is your output;

**EDIT:**

In order to get longest consecutive days for each merchant check this <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c29d2b/2)</kbd>

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. Would need an early morning, a cup of strong coffe and fresh head to really understand it. Thank you!

Comment: Sure. Take your time. :) @Dennis